# gradle use class from maven build

Tags: gradle

Hy i have written a java Library an I want to use it in the Gradle script. What I have done:
Added the repository:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "../Projectname/maven_repo"
    }
}
```

Added the Dependency:

```
dependencies {
    classpath group: 'my.group.id', name: 'Projectname', version: '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

And now i want to use the Library in a Task:

```
task myTask () {
    def file = file("${buildDir}/ws/.metadata/.log")
    def htmlParser = new my.package.Projectname()
}
```

Now I always get the exception on the Buildserver that he isn’t able to find the class.
Thx for the Help.

Comment: if you want to use it in your build.gradle, you should add the dependencies in the buildscript {} tag.

Comment: thx now it works. @dwursteisen